# Using the Weibull Distribution, derive $E(X^k)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

If $X$~WEI$(\theta,\beta)$, derive $E(X^k)$ assuming $k\gt-\beta$.

Note that $X$~WEI$(\theta,\beta)=\frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}x^{\beta -1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}}$

I am having a very difficult time attempting this problem. I start with:

$$E(X^k)=\int_0^{\infty}x^k \frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}x^{\beta -1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}}dx$$

$$=\frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}\int_0^{\infty}x^{\beta+k-1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}}dx$$

It was hinted to me to attempt substitution, so I let $({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}=t$

Based on a similar problem I did, I have the suspicion that I need to get it in the form of:

$$\int_0^{\infty}t^{k-1}e^{-t}dt$$
which is the gamma function.

With the substitution $({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}=t$ we quickly get the $e^{-t}$ portion. I'm having trouble finding the steps to make the connection between the rest of the problem and $t^{k-1}$. Or, is this not the correct approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So why don't you follow the substitution through? what integral do you get, please write it here. I think this is a really poor effort... you just wrote down the hint someone gave you, showed no actual work done by yourself and expect an answer? when you do the substitution, you see it exactly the gamma integral you wrote down with different coefficient. why don't you just do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution
Wiki has the MGF.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate $\int_0^{\infty}x^k \frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}x^{\beta -1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}}dx$ using integration by parts $k$ times, if you do it you finally get $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\beta}{\theta^{\beta}}x^{\beta -1}e^{-({x}/{\theta})^{\beta}} dx$ and you know that it's equals $1$.